# how to insert custom object in std::map

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert a reference to my object, but i am getting large number of errors. What do i need to modify in the custom object, so that it can be inserted successfully?

The code is shown below:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
            cout << "default constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(A & a)
    {
            cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    A & operator=(A & a)
    {
            cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
            return *this;
    }

    ~A()
    {
            cout << "destructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    map<string, A&> m1;
    A a;
    m1["a"] = a;
    return 0;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

1. It is possible to create a map with reference such as `map<string, A&>`
2. The error was in usage of [] operator. By making following change, the code works

   ```
   typedef map<string, A&> mymap;

   int main()
   {
      mymap m1;
      A a;
      cout << &a << endl;
      m1.insert(make_pair<string, A&>("a", a));
      mymap::iterator it = m1.find("a");
      A &b = (*it).second;
      cout << &b << endl; // same memory address as a
      return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is very useful website.

Comment: Note that your copy constructor `A(A&a)` is not the one you want -- you want `A(A const&)`, and the same for `operator=`.  This is unrelated to your problem, which is solved below.

Answer (score 4):

You can't store references in `map`. Use pointers instead.

Replace:

```
map<string, A&> m1;
```

With:

```
map<string, A*> m1;
```

Or better yet (Thanks WhozCraig!):

```
map<string, shared_ptr<A> > m1;
```

Comment: +1 And use pointers with brains (i.e. smart pointers; not naked pointers). Though I would prefer to just store the actual *objects* in the map

Answer (score 2):

You can not use references as the key- or value-type of an container. You need to use a pointer, preferably a smart pointer like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or, if this is not too expensive, you could store copies of the objects. Here's some options:

```
map<string,A> mc; // stores copies of A

map<string,A*> mp; // you need to take care of memory management - avoid that

map<string,shared_ptr<A>> msp; // prefered
```

to use the latter, you could create and insert elements like this:

```
msp["a"] = make_shared<A>();
```

Hope it helps as a start.

Comment: The copy ctor and assignment operator will have to be changed to use `map<string,A>` it does not compile as is

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: True, but I see it as more-or-less unrelated as it should be fixed anyways, not just if OP is trying to store it in a `map`. He will automatically stumble upon that problem when he tries the first approach and either he knows how to fix it or he knows how to ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to have a `map` that only stores references. This is a bit impossible because references usually have to be initialized with a reference the moment they are brought into conception

When you use `m1["a"]`, that function by itself has to default-construct and item in-place before letting you assign to it (you can't default-construct a reference). If you're trying to avoid having a copy made, you can use the `emplace` flavor of functions to have the object constructed in-place, or just have `map<std::string, A>` and make your life easy.

If you need it to not make a copy, you can also try using a `map<std::string, A*>` that stores pointers. You'll be responsible for cleaning up the memory yourself, however (unless you use `std::unique_ptr` or a friend of that).